# How can I load a material within a GTFL model dynamically?

Tags: three.js

I'm learning ThreeJS. I'm loading an external GFTL model (a car), and I want to load a material (simulating the car painting). I don't want to load a GFTL model with an embedded material, since I intend to change this material by a user interface.

```js
let loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(BeetleGLTF, function (gltf) {
    const car = gltf.scene.children[0];
    
    car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    animate();
  });
```

This is how my model renders on the browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the damagedhemlmet in the models folder for the examples of three has everything hook up you import the damagedhelmet copy everything in the shader/ shading panels go to you model delete you shader paste the copyied damagedhelmet shader in your gtfl shader project in blender in shader then apply the the textures images that come with the damaged helmet reapply the paths by filenames or then swith the basecolor image to your base color image you can do a bake tutorial in blender to get the basecolor image then export as a glb